# How to find rows from a Datatable

Tags: database, vb.net, datatable

I'm working on a login system with a password reset feature. i'm trying to figure out how to output the secret question from a matched username. my idea was to get the row index of the matched username then then output the question using the row index. also is it possible to put the returned row index in a variabale? i'm kinda new to vb.net soooo if you have better ideas let me know and i'll thank you in return :P

```
Dim con As SqlConnection
Dim command As SqlCommand
Dim ad As SqlDataAdapter
Dim ds As DataSet
Public constring As String = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\almond\Desktop\Ticket System\Ticket System\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"

 If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter your username")
    End If
    Dim q2 As String = "SELECT * FROM tblusers WHERE username = @username "

    con = New SqlConnection
    con.ConnectionString = constring
    con.Open()
    Dim command As New SqlCommand(q2, con)
    command.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
    Dim ad As New SqlDataAdapter(command)
    ad = New SqlDataAdapter(command)
    Dim table As New DataTable
    ad.Fill(table)

    If table.Rows.Count() = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Account Not Found")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: You should show us your data schema, so we can see what options do you have

Comment: Why would you need a row index? Surely user names are unique so if there will always be either zero or one match. You've already handled the case where there's zero so if you get past there then you know for a fact that there's one row in your `DataTable`, so you know that the index must be 0.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y06xa2h1.aspx  
this link shows how to find row by using .Select() of datatable